# In Compose, passing a method reference as a parameter to a composable triggers recomposition

Tags: android

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyScreen(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    // Changed uiState value.
    val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    
    // This causes recomposition even though it doesn't use uiState.
    Ui(
        onClick = viewModel::onClick
    )
}
```

To my knowledge, when passing an method from a ViewModel, directly passing the method's reference can prevent unnecessary recompositions.

However, in practice, when I pass a method's reference to a composable in this way, recomposition occurs every time despite the method's hashcode matching.

How can I effectively prevent recomposition?

Comment: still no answer? . i am facing this issue too . compose is all over the place